# $T$, $S$ are lineary dependent $\Leftrightarrow$ $[T]_B$, $[S]_B$ are lineary dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

EDIT: I see in the comments that my question is not clear enough so I will explain:

if I want to check whether $T$, $S$ are linearly independent or not, I will just pick an  easy to work with, basis for $V$ and then check if $[T]_B$, $[S]_B$ are linearly independent. so the real question is can I do that? and why?

Comment: Hint: Two vectors $\;u,v\;$ in *any* vector space over some given field $\;F\;$ are linearly dependent iff $\;u=\alpha v\;,\;\;\alpha\in F\;$

Comment: Let's add $\alpha\neq 0$...

Comment: The definition of linear dependence does not even involve a basis. What do you mean by "linearly dependent with respect to a basis"? The coordinate vectors are linearly dependent iff the vectors themself are? For that: Check that isomorphisms preserve linear dependence and that choosing coordinates gives an isomorphism.

Comment: I edited my question, so it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vector space $V$, such that dim$(V)=n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_n$ (column vectors with $n$ components), but even more than this, the isomorphism is a linear isomorphism, that is it preserves the structure of the vector space. To prove that this is indeed so you have to prove that the function $\phi$ mapping each vector of $V$ to its coordinate vector, is:

- functional
- injective and surjective
- preserves scalar multiplication and vector addition (this is where you add the extra conditions of preserving the structure of the vector space)

It is a quite straightforward direct proof, and most linear algebra books have it.

I hope this helps.